# Add Cassandra 2.1 nodes to a Cassandra 1.2.15 cluster?

Tags: cassandra

Is it possible to extend an existing Cassandra 1.2.15 cluster by adding Cassandra 2.1 nodes to it?
The idea, here, is to be able, via another new software, to access the data produced by the one using 1.2.15.

I haven't yet been able to find the answer on the web.

Comment: I'd be surprised. Have you considered upgrading the existing nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend this.  As stated in the DataStax Upgrade Guide (section titled "[Version Restrictions](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/upgrade/doc/upgrade/cassandra/upgradeC_c.html)") Cassandra 2.1 is not sstable-compatible with any 1.x version.  By doing so, you'll be putting your cluster into what is known as an "upgrade state," and [subject to the following restrictions](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/upgrade/doc/upgrade/datastax_enterprise/upgrdDetails.html?scroll=upgrdDetails__upgrdGenLim):

- Do not run nodetool repair.
- Do not use new features.
- Do not issue these types of queries during a rolling restart: DDL, TRUNCATE.
- Do not change security credentials or permissions.

If you want to run 2.1, you should upgrade.  Of course, (as per the first document I mentioned above) you'll need to upgrade your 1.2 nodes to 2.0.7 first, and then upgrade them to 2.1.  Check the DataStax documentation for [upgrade instructions](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/upgrade/doc/upgrade/cassandra/upgradeCassandraDetails.html).

Although, you might have to augment some of that, because DataStax has not published a community version of 2.1 yet (I think they're still on 2.0.10), so you'd have to grab 2.1 from the [project site](http://cassandra.apache.org/) itself.

EDIT-

A DataStax community version of Cassandra 2.1 was made available for download last night.